# Understanding recursion using all possible combinations in an array

Tags: java, recursion, combinations, permutation, mathematical-expressions

I'm trying to understand recursion with the help of few examples. I found this example of printing all possible combinations of `r` elements in a given array of size `n` using recursion.

[Print all possible combinations of r elements in a given array of size n.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/)

They are using the idea behind the expression:

[image]

What i'm trying to understand here is the conceptual meaning of this expression. I have read different articles but couldn't find a satisfactory explanation.

A mathematical or practical example which uses this expression would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are different notations for combinations in math:

[image]

Using the first of them, your formula is

[image]

The left-hand side of it means: *The number of ways* we can select `r` elements from the set of `n` elements.

Let `S` be a set of `n` elements. Let `x` be the last element of it, so the set `S` is for example

```
+-------------+---+
| a b c d e f | x |
+-------------+---+
```

Let `C` is an arbitrary combination of `r` elements from the set `S`.

(Particularly, to follow just introduced example, you may imagine that `r = 3`, and  `n = 7` - as the set is `{a, b, c, d, e, f, x}`.)

There are only 2 possibilities:

1. `C` contains `x` (e. g. `C = {a, d, x}`), or
2. `C` does not contain `x`  (e. g. `C = {a, d, e}`).

If `C` contains `x`, then remaining `(r - 1)` elements (i. e. `2` in our example) are chosen from remaining `(n - 1)` elements (i. e. from `{a, b, c, d, e, f}` in our example) - so there are

[image]

ways how to select such combination.

If `C` does not contain `x`, then *all* `r` elements are chosen from remaining `(n - 1)` elements - so there are

[image]

ways how to select such combination.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation!! Can you expand this one level more.
Say if c contains x and i expand C(n-1,r-1) meaning I have to choose r=2 now from n-1=6 elements now.
And say if c doesn't contain x and i expand C(n-1,r) and i'm choosing r=3 from n-1=6 elements now.

Does that make sense or am i missing something and would x be same for this expansion as well.

Comment: @AnkushDutt, yes, you are right. `x` is always the same element. By other words, you either select *trinities* from `{a, b, c, d, e, f}`, or *`x` plus pairs* from the same set `{a, b, c, d, e, f}`. - Please consider to accept my answer if it was useful for you.